# Expect: 100-Continue header with XmlHTTPRequest

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-1.1

How do I force XmlHttpRequest to add Expect: 100-continue header? How can I make use of this feature in desktop browsers world?

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var dataToSend = new FormData();
dataToSend.append('some', 'data');
dataToSend.append('token', 'secret-token');

xmlhttp.open("POST", "/post", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Expect", "100-continue");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Custom-Header", "This is custom data");
xmlhttp.send(dataToSend);
```

Here is the TCP Dump output piece

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 243
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Custom-Header: This is custom data
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AAKgYIit0sVHMcI7na85UR_Na.o7uSDBEidLEyQ3cTaGyXlMrPiF3vADrwpnCrkCrJBD0

------WebKitFormBoundary9agFn5mlxh7SUBf7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="some"

data
------WebKitFormBoundary9agFn5mlxh7SUBf7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"

secret-token
------WebKitFormBoundary9agFn5mlxh7SUBf7--
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot force the `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()` method to add the `Expect` header for security reasons, as you can read in the [W3C XMLHttpRequest specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method):

> The setRequestHeader(header, value) method must run these steps:
>
> 1. If the state is not OPENED, throw an "InvalidStateError" exception and terminate these steps.
> 2. If the send() flag is set, throw an "InvalidStateError" exception and terminate these steps.
> 3. If header does not match the field-name production, throw a "SyntaxError" exception and terminate these steps.
> 4. If value does not match the field-value production, throw a "SyntaxError" exception and terminate these steps (note: The empty string is legal and represents the empty header value).
> 5. Terminate these steps if header is a case-insensitive match for one of the following headers:
>
>    - Accept-Charset
>    - Accept-Encoding
>    - Access-Control-Request-Headers
>    - Access-Control-Request-Method
>    - Connection Content-Length
>    - Cookie
>    - Cookie2
>    - Blockquote
>    - Date
>    - DNT
>    - Expect
>    - Host
>    - Keep-Alive Origin
>    - Referer
>    - TE
>    - Trailer
>    - Transfer-Encoding
>    - Upgrade
>    - User-Agent
>    - Via
>
> ...or if the start of header is a case-insensitive match for Proxy- or Sec- (including when header is just Proxy- or Sec-).
>
> The above headers are controlled by the user agent to let it control those aspects of transport. This guarantees data integrity to some extent. Header names starting with Sec- are not allowed to be set to allow new headers to be minted that are guaranteed not to come from XMLHttpRequest.

As a further reference:

- [Webkit Tests "set-dangerous-headers.html"](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/LayoutTests/http/tests/xmlhttprequest/set-dangerous-headers.html)

Some browsers (Chrome, for example) will also display an error in their "JavaScript Console":

[image: Unsafe header]

Comment: I knew that. And it's mean that there is no way to utilize this useful feature in browsers. And your answer just confirmed my thoughts.